# How to display input field in web using lotus notes value after saved through web browser?

Tags: html, lotus-notes, jquery-ui-datepicker, lotus-domino

I have a form in a browser. All field I use using text field and there is one field I am using input field using html which is date picker field name Assign Date. I also use jquery to display this date picker with field value from lotus domino.

[image: date]

So when I edit another field, then I also edit assigned date and choose any date and saved. Every other fields is saved but not for assigned date field. The field value did saved and display in lotus domino but not display in web browser. My input code as below:

```
<div class="form-group" id="date-container">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="P-AssignDate" name="PAssignDate" autocomplete="off" required>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something? How can I display the value in my input field? Or does input field cannot displayed a field? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like hand-crafted HTML that you are generating on your Notes form. Your  element in the HTML has no value="xxx" property. It will always be empty when you redisplay the form in the browser. So, assuming this is static pass-through HTML on your form, you can add static text for the value property and the quotes and use computed text inside the quotes.

```
value="<computed text goes here>"
```

The formula for the computed text element will refer to your stored field by its name.

Comment: Should also be pointed out that when you hand craft a field, it doesn't get saved with the document.  You have to do it yourself during the WebQuerySave event.

Comment: As I recall, it does get saved if you have a hidden editable field on the form that matches the name of the hand-crafted <input> element.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have a hidden editable field in the form. So thats why on my lotus notes is saved, but not in my web. And I follow your answer and it show the value when I insert computed text. Thank you @RichardSchwartz.